# Changing the end of a line whenever it contains a specific string

Tags: text-processing, vim

I have file where I want to add some text at the end of each line whenever it contains a specific string :

```
output(),
output(abcdefgh),
```

becomes

```
output());
output(abcdefgh));
```

So basically I want to detect the  `"output(`  remove `,` and add   `);` to the end of each line that meets the mentioned condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim:

```
:g/output(/ s/,$/);/
```

`:g /pattern/` runs the command on all lines matching the `pattern`, and the `s` command then replaces a line-end `,` with a `);`.

Comment: a nitpick which needs clarity from OP... this doesn't necessarily match towards end of line... say there is a line `"output()," foo bar "a,"`... and I think my editing of question may be wrong too regards to quote

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want

```
otherline(),
... output(),
... output(abcdefgh),
output
```

to be translated to

```
otherline(),
... output());
... output(abcdefgh));
output
```

I sugest the use of Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/output\(.*?\)\K,$/);/'
```